# Ruby gems missing when run from Xcode shell script

Tags: ruby, xcode, gruntjs, compass-sass

I'm attempting to run a grunt script to compile a bunch of stuff, including `grunt-contrib-compass` from Xcode. Running `grunt debug` works fine from outside of Xcode, but not when invoked as a shell script as part of a build phase in Xcode.

running `grunt debug` I receive:

> /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s)
>   (Gem::LoadError)

Having loaded in my PATH variables at the top of the script with:

```
PATH=$(bash -l -c 'echo $PATH')
```

Xcode seems to be loading in the correct versions of ruby & gem:

```
which ruby     ->  /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
which compass  ->  /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass
which gem      ->  /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem
```

These are the same as those reported from bash.

However,`gem query --local` returns a different list when executed within Xcode than when run from bash. This list does not contain compass - I guess this might be why I receive the `Could not find 'compass'` error, any idea what I can do to fix this?

Here's my gem env, as reported from the shell script executed by Xcode:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/MY_USER/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /Users/MY_USER/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
     - /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /opt/local/bin
     - /opt/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin
     - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
     - /Users/MY_USER/bin
     - /Users/MY_USER/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
     - /Users/MY_USER/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
     - /Users/MY_USER/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a `Gemfile` and running `bundle exec grunt debug`?

Comment: Do you mean I could run the `grunt cli` via `budle exec`..?

Answer (score 2):

So I've ended up cheating -

```
echo $(bash -l -c  "source ~/.bashrc && cd $myProjectLocation && grunt debug")
```

runs the grunt command in a new bash instance, which does not inherit Xcode's environment variables, and is the same as bash outside of Xcode.

It's not perfect though - while echoing out the result of bash gives me all the log messages, they're poorly formatted, and it doesn't halt execution of the main script if there's an error.

So ideally I'd still like a proper solution to my original question, if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this?

Comment: Yes - we no longer use anything that depends on ruby, and have move to using libsass for building sass!

This works fine as part of a script build phase in xcode:

`source ~/.bash_profile && sh scripts/build.sh` when the build.sh script might contain `gulp build` etc.